# Spigot server on Rasperry Pi 512MB failing with Connection Refused Error in Client

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, minecraft

So, I installed a MC Spigot server as per this [page](http://picraftbukkit.webs.com/pi-minecraft-server-how-to) using Java 1.8.0 Hardfloat. I'm running all this on Arch on a 512MB Pi. I believe the downloading of Java and Spigot went fine (no errors during download or extraction), but when I go to start the server, it does this:

```
$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx496M -jar /home/server-god/spigot.jar nogui

Warning, your max perm gen size is not set or less than 128mb. It is recommended you restart Java with the following argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
Loading libraries, please wait...
Killed
```

I tried that max perm arg and got this:

```
$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Xms256M -Xmx496M -jar /home/server-god/spigot.jar nogui

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
Loading libraries, please wait...
Killed
```

This is really annoying! All of the tutorials use Java 1.8 and say they work fine!

I have tried connecting from Minecraft and get a `java.net.ConnectionExcept: Connection refused` error in both MC 1.7.4 snapshot 14w02c and 1.7.2.

What is causing the server to get killed & how can I keep it up running even when I log off SSH?

**EDIT**

Tried it with Java 1.7 Hardfloat and it is no longer saying `Killed` at the end of the command. However, it does just go back to the bash prompt. Could I get help on this please?

```
$ sudo /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx496M -jar /home/server-god/spigot.jar nogui
Warning, your max perm gen size is not set or less than 128mb. It is recommended you restart Java with the following argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
Loading libraries, please wait...
```

**EDIT**

Running the command `ps -e | grep java` after running the server start command (above) returns nothing, so my guess is that Java is getting killed somehow, or there is an error in the Spigot jar. However, I am not receiving any error messages, so I don't really know what to do!

Comment: did you port forward?

Comment: @fox_news Yes...I ended up getting it working using Raspbian, however, I still would like to get it working on Arch, so I am not self-answering this one.

Answer (score 1):

You said you have tried with java 1.8 with MaxPermSize

```
$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Xms256M -Xmx496M -jar /home/server-god/spigot.jar nogui
```

and with Java 1.7 without MaxPermSize :

```
$ sudo /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx496M -jar /home/server-god/spigot.jar nogui
```

But as some modpack for minecraft seem to have issues with java 1.8 have you tried Java 1.7 with MaxPermSize ?

```
 $ sudo /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Xms256M -Xmx496M -jar /home/server-god/spigot.jar nogui
```

It could be a comment but I can only post answers right now (weird rule of Stack Overflow ^^)

Comment: I haven't tried Java 7, I may try that in the future. I would *prefer* to use Java 8 hardfloat because of the speed difference (hardware floating vs software floating.) Thanks for pointers, I will be sure to try these out. As for why you can't comment, that's because you are below 50 rep. It's in place to protect the site from being spammed via comments, as that would be an easy place to strike. Read here if you want to know a little more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment